# Sending email (through GMail) through windows command line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, gmail

So, platform is Windows XP, cmd is the preferred command line and GMail is where I have my email.

I'm interested in the possibility of sending mail through the command line, as lately I've been sending a lot of *one-liners* concerning some ... well, some work stuff, to a group of two or three people.

Is there such a possibility and what would be needed for that? I've googled a bit on the subject, but get a lot of *"expired" articles* and linux-related answers.

Has anyone managed to setup this, and if so, would you be willing to share a word or two on the subject?

Comment: blat is commonly used for cmd line email in win. This may be useful [Using Blat, Stunnel and Gmail Together](http://www.jeffkastner.com/2010/01/blat-stunnel-and-gmail) (I have not used it myself hence comment only)

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing Sendmail on your box and configure it to use Gmail as its SMTP server. Found this like on how to set that up http://drewdahl.com/2010/02/18/setup-sendmail-to-use-gmails-smtp-server/

Comment: @Shocm-The page that you linked explains the method to do for Fedora not for windows. Or is it applicable for windows also, if I'm wrong?

Comment: Yeah but I believe you can install sendmail on Windows as well so it's just a matter of converting over the configuration settings required for sendmail.